# Find sub-string and return it plus previous 17 characters

Tags: java, windows, vba, batch-file

I want to be able to search a text file in Windows for a sting ("A R") and return the every instance of the string plus the previous 17 characters. The characters contain numbers, dashes, and slashes. Unfortunately, the strings that I am looking for are contained in a mess of information, so simply returning each line that "A R" is found on isn't really an option.

I have tried to devise a way to simple use FINDSTR in CMD and redirect the output to a results.txt, but the FINDSTR won't let me pass so many characters (see below).

`findstr /r /c:"[0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z][0-Z]A R" CombineXML.txt >results.txt`

Results should look something like:

05-24-00-212-805-A R

25-23-00-300-801-A R

79-33-03-400-801-A R

I only have access to NetBeans (not very experienced in Java, though), VBA, and Windows Batch Scripting (company computer = no admin rights, no Python, no Visual Studio...grrr).

I've been racking my brain for a week trying to figure this out.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? If Windows 7 or later, is Powershell or VBScript/JScript blocked?

Comment: `findstr` is not able to extract from a string, you just give a search string (with very limited REGEX support) and always get back the whole line.

Comment: In VBA, can you add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"? If so, you can do it in VBA. Of course, you could use VBScript itself, if you have access to it. It's similar to VBA.

Comment: Thank you for the information Shephan. I'll abandon the FINDSTR idea, then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jeff Zeitlin. I tried to install the Windows PowerShell from Microsoft, but needed admin access. VBScript and JScript don't appear to be blocked, though. I am using Windows 7 Professional (64-bit).

Comment: You might be interested in [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). Still not familiar with it, but this should work: `type CombineXML.txt |JREPL.BAT "(.{18}A R)" "$1" /match >results.txt`

Comment: Stephan, Your answer did the trick. Thanks! Please post JREPL.BAT as the answer, so I can vote and close.

Comment: @UnityIlluminateWorld: done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr` is very limited in it's capability, so it's useless here. But there is a great tool [jrepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to do all kind of REGEX searching and replacing. The following line should do what you want:

```
 type CombineXML.txt |JREPL.BAT "(.{17}A R)" "$1" /match >results.txt
```

Comment: The parentheses are not needed in the search string, and the replace string is ignored when /MATCH is used, I prefer to use /F InputFile /O OutputFile instead of a pipe and redirection. So a simpler alternate command is `jrepl ".{17}A R" "" /match /f CombineXML.txt /o results.txt`. Use CALL JREPL if you put the command in a batch script without a ppe.